# Are the known exoplanets representative of the population of exoplanets?

Tags: astrophysics, exoplanets

An [article about the recent release of a large number of confirmed exoplanets](http://news.yahoo.com/population-known-alien-planets-nearly-doubles-nasa-discovers-191250870.html) states that most of the 715 newly announced exoplanets orbit very close to their host stars.

Do the theories predict that this is a representative sample and that most planets are very close to their host stars? Or is it just that our current detection techniques are predisposed to finding only those planets close to their stars (because the sensors look for dimming of the host star for example)?

Comment: I was under the impression that it was the latter, although I admittedly don't know much astronomy.

Comment: @DumpsterDoofus I would agree, but I don't know much either which is why I'm appealing to the experts! I know both dimming of the star and wobble in the orbit are used, so we might only be able to get close and/or massive planets. But I also don't know the theory, so it's possible that we would expect far more planets in close also.

Comment: It's the latter. The heavier a planet and the closer to the star, the easier it is to detect, so there's a clear bias. I wonder if any planet of the solar system would be detectable with our techniques if it's an average distance away from us.

Comment: @pfnuesel If you can state that from a position of personal expertise or can back it up (or preferably both) it is the kernel of an answer.

Comment: The CCDs on Kepler are (well, *were* since it's broke) indeed looking for periodic dips in front of the host star, so it's biased to edge-on systems but does not care for size.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The known exoplanets are not representive.  Each discovery technique has its own bias.

For the transit of star technique, the probabilty that a planet transits the star, as observed from a distance, is proportional to the radius of the star and inversely proportional to the orbital radius (semi-major axis).  Also, below a certain size, there will be insufficient signal to noise to detect the planet.  So the transit technique is biased toward planets orbiting close to their star, planets of larger stars, and planets that are above a signal/noise threshold in size.

The radial velocity of star technique is biased toward finding large mass planets close to their stars.

The direct imaging technique is biased toward finding large planets far away from their stars.